# Substring query not working properly if strings are repeating

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to replace last 5 digits of a phone number.
 I wrote this query:

```
update users
    set
        mobile = Replace(mobile, SUBSTRING(mobile, 6, 5), 'xxxxx')
    where
        email="xxxxx@gmail.com"
```

It is working fine for numbers like 8100343397
But for numbers like 9090909090 it is replacing from the 2nd digit instead of 6th digit.

I want to know the reason why.

I know it will work with left and concat.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using `replace()`?

```
update users
    set mobile = concat(left(model, length(mobile) - 5), 'xxxxx')
    where email = 'xxxxx@gmail.com';
```

Just take all but the last five characters and then append the new values that you want.

Comment: Gordon is correct, but to explain what you are seeing - you are calling `REPLACE` and passing in a string of characters that it will look for. Despite you passing in the last 5 digits (`09090`) of the phone number, since it is a repeat of the first 5 characters (starting at the second digit: `09090`) it will replace that first occurrence instead of the last.